# How do I bind the data of a custom UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I just setup a project and added a custom UserControl that looks like this.

```
<Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserViewModel.Users}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <controls:UserCard/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

As you can see I tried binding the `Text` property buti it doesn't bind.
Now there could be a lot of reasons to why it's behaving like this so I will try to narrow it down.

I've created a BaseViewModel that will hold my ViewModels and it looks like this.

```
public class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public UserViewModel UserViewModel { get; set; } = new UserViewModel();
    }
```

And then I've setup my ViewModel like this

```
public class UserViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();

        public UserViewModel()
        {
            Users.Add(new User{Name = "Riley"});
            Users.Add(new User{Name = "Riley1"});
        }
    }
```

Simple, now I do have a ObservableObject that looks like this and deals with the INPC

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And in my `MainView.xaml`
I've set the DataContext like so

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new BaseViewModel();
    }
}
```

It's the exact same for the UserControl

And this is where I actually add the UserControl so it displays in the MainWindow

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserViewModel.Users}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <controls:UserCard/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>
```

Now the issue is that it doesn't bind the Data, I want to display the `Name` property from the Model but it's not displaying it and I am not sure why, if I try to bind it to a TextBlock property in the MainView directly it works fine.

I am unsure to why it's behaving like this and I would like to understand why.
Do I need to make use of DependencyProperties? Or is it just a case of me creating a new instance of the BaseViewModel? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I don't think you have the correct XAML for the user control... looks like it's the XAML for the MainWindow with your testing TextBlock in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainViewWindow` contains an ItemsControl with the binding `ItemsSource="{Binding UserViewModel.Users}"`, with each item being displayed with a `<controls:UserCard/>`. But your user control is then trying to bind to the list again with `"{Binding UserViewModel.Users}"`. Why are you trying to display a list inside another list?

I suspect the problem here is that you think your custom UserControl's `DataContext` is still pointing to the BaseViewModel, like its parent. It isn't. The `DataContext` of each item in an ItemsControl points to it's own associated element in the list, i.e. an instance of type `User`.

UPDATED: Let's say you have a main view model with a list of child view models, like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MyChildViewModel[] MyItems { get; } =
    {
        new MyChildViewModel{MyCustomText = "Tom" },
        new MyChildViewModel{MyCustomText = "Dick" },
        new MyChildViewModel{MyCustomText = "Harry" }
    };
}

public class MyChildViewModel
{
    public string MyCustomText { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say you set your MainWindow's DataContext to an instance of MainViewModel and add a ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" />
```

If you do this you'll see the following:

[image]

What's happening here is that the ListView is creating a container (of type ContentPresenter) for each of the three elements in the list, and setting each one's DataContext to point to its own instance of MyChildViewModel. By default ContentPresenter just calls 'ToString()' on its DataContext, so you're just seeing the name of the class it's pointing to. If you add a `ToString()` operator to your MyChildViewModel like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"MyChildViewModel: {this.MyCustomText}";
}
```

... then you'll see that displayed instead:

[image]

You can also override the ListViewItem's template entirely, and since it already points to its associated instance of MyChildViewModel you can just bind directly to its properties:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- One of these gets created for each element in the list -->
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="CornflowerBlue" CornerRadius="5" Padding="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyCustomText}" Foreground="Yellow" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Which will change the display to this:

[image]

Make sense?

Comment: Ohhh! So it inherits the `DataContext` from the parent in the XAML?

Comment: In most cases, yes. A notable exception, which applies to the case you've shown above, is ListView and ItemsCollection etc where each child item has it's DataContext set to the list element.

Comment: So with ListViews and ItemsCollection this does not apply? Sorry if I am misinterpreting this.

Comment: ListView (as an example) will inherit its parent's DataContext if you don't explicitly override it, but all of its child items (i.e. ListBoxViewItem) will have their DataContext set to their corresponding item whatever their parent ListBox's `ItemSource` is set to.

Comment: So let's say your MainWindow has its DataContext set to a MainViewModel, and your MainViewModel has a list of items called `MyItems` which is an array of MyChildViewModel. If you put a ListView on your main window then it will inherit it's DataContext from its parent (ie MainViewModel). If that ListView binds its ItemsSource to "MyItems" then it will create a child ListBoxViewItem for each of your MyChildViewModel, and each one will have it's DataContext set to it's own instance of MyChildViewModel.